# Asterisk resend call invite

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I need to resend a call invitation within a certain time to a user if he is offline. Is it possible to do this via dialplan or I need a special script for this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to resend invite. You need to re-call.

Yes, you can do it using dialplan by multiple methods.

If you are using .call files you have MaxRetries: X params for that. It will do automatically.

**Syntax of call files**

Specify where and how to call

```
Channel: <channel>: Channel to use for the call.
CallerID: “name” <number> Caller ID, Please note: It may not work if you do not respect the format: CallerID: “Some Name” <1234>

MaxRetries: <number> Number of retries before failing (not including the initial attempt, e.g. 0 = total of 1 attempt to make the call). Default is 0.

RetryTime: <number> Seconds between retries, Don’t hammer an unavailable phone. The default is 300 (5 min).
WaitTime: <number> Seconds to wait for an answer. Default is 45.
Account: Set the account code to use.
```